# sql datetime converted to specific day if between certain times

Tags: sql-server, datetime, case, iif

I have a string of datetime records. I'd like to make a case condition or if statement which reads the datetime value and assigns this to a specific day.

The day range is 2:45PM up to the next day at 2:45PM. This range would be considered the 'next day'

Ex. Time of post is `3:42 PM 11/12/2016`, therefore this would read as `11/13/2016`. If this post was made at 2:42 PM 11/12/2016, then this would have read 11/12/2016.

So far don't believe CONVERT(date, 'datetime') will work due to time range constraints.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use DATEADD function to add time to the date so it gets to the next day. For 2:45PM you'll need to add 9:15.

Comment: the 2:45 criteria is fixed, but the datetime values can be at any time of day and on any day. I don't see how this would work. Can't put in a fixed value of 9:15, etc.

Comment: @Nicho247 It works just fine for any time during the day.

Answer (score 0):

Think I got it...check if datetime time value is above 2:45, if so, then convert to date and add a day, else convert to date.

```
CASE
    WHEN    CAST (MAIN.TimeOfRftDecision AS Time) > '14:45:00' THEN DATEADD(dd,1,CONVERT (Date, MAIN.TimeOfRftDecision))
    ELSE    CONVERT (Date, MAIN.TimeOfRftDecision)
END AS 'DayOfRft'
```